# How to Clear SharePoint Designer Cache?

Tags: sharepoint, web, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I created a `workflow` in **SharePoint Designer 2013**, but I can't see my changes.

I think that **SharePoint Designer** is cached.

How can I clear this cache?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a batch file that I use to quickly clear anything that SharePoint Designer might have cached locally.

```
cd "%appdata%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
del *.web /S /Q "%appdata%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
dir "%appdata%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
@echo off
echo Cache is cleared (you can close this) If you want to be very thorough: 
pause
cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\"
rmdir /S /Q "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\."
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache"
dir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache"
ECHO:All done!
pause
```

There's 2 parts to it: the first part *sometimes* solves my SPD issues, the second part will always clear it out, *but* it will also clear out all the history of what sites I've connected to.

Answer (score 3):

To Clear SharePoint Designer Cache, follow below steps:

1) Delete all the files from location

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

2) Delete all the files from location

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

3) Disable caching from SharePoint Designer tool options:

Uncheck -- Cache Site Data Across SharePoint Designer Sessions

Reference: http://codemanga.com/index.php/2015/07/15/clear-sharepoint-designer-cache/